# ElasticSearch filtering with geo distance

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I'm attempting to filter data with both geo distance and fields like 'has_cctv' or 'has_instant_bookings'.

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": 10000,
          "lat_lng": {
            "lat": "51.5073509",
            "lon": "-0.1277583"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried many combinations of filtering using terms but can't seem to get past errors. For example:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms": [
          {"term": {"has_cctv": 1}}
        ],
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": 10000,
          "lat_lng": {
            "lat": "51.5073509",
            "lon": "-0.1277583"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me '[terms] filter does not support [has_cctv] within lookup element'. Could this be a problem with my query, or a problem with the way the data is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here goes the correct query:

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "term": {
               "has_cctv": {
                  "value": 1
               }
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
               "distance": 10000,
               "lat_lng": {
                  "lat": "51.5073509",
                  "lon": "-0.1277583"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Just make sure that lat_lng is stored as geo_point

Thanks
Bharvi

Comment: I had written query for a single term matching. If you have multiple conditions you can write down a bool query like :   "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                     "term": {
                        "has_cctv": {
                           "value": 1
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ],"must": [
                  {"term": {
                     "has_instant_bookings": {
                        "value": 1
                     }
                  }}
               ]
            }
         }

Comment: Your comment underneath this post solved it, thank you so much! You might want to update the original answer for anyone else who's having a similar issue can see the answer a little clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use an `and` filter and group the two filters together. And a comparison between `bool filter` and `and/or/not filters`: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": {
          "filters": [
            {
              "term": {
                "has_cctv": "1"
              }
            },
            {
              "geo_distance": {
                "distance": 10000,
                "lat_lng": {
                  "lat": "51.5073509",
                  "lon": "-0.1277583"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the sort by distance feature is lost if you lose this , it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors.

As you have more than one filter, you need to add a `bool filter` and put each filter in a `must` clause.
Then you don't need a `terms` filter here but a `term` filter.